# asp.net mvc Getting values from Html.Checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I want to be able to select a few boxes and send the strings correlating to them. The problem however is that I don't know how to catch the values in the controller.

One important issue is that I do not want to bind it to a model! Hopefully you can help me find a solution that fits in this image

cshtml file:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.WikiPage>
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeletePages", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
 <ul>
    @foreach (var item in @Model)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.CheckBox(item.Title)
            @Html.Label(item.Title)
        </li>
    }
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Delete pages" />
}
```

And here is the part in the controller. String... will be null and I don't know what I should put in there to catch the values

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeletePages(String... Titles)
    {

        removePages(Titles);
        List<WikiPage> pages = db.WikiPages.ToList();

        return View(pages);
    }
```

Hope you can help me!

Kind regards

Comment: `@Html.CheckBox()` is for binding to a `bool`, not a string. If you want to post back an array of strings, then generate your inputs manually `<input type="checkbox" name="titles" value="@item.Title />` and change the method to `public ActionResult DeletePages(string[] titles)`

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.WikiPage>
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeletePages", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
 <ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <label>@item.Title
                <input type="checkbox" name="titles" value="@item.Title />
            </label>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Delete pages" />
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeletePages(string[] titles)
{
    removePages(titles);
    List<WikiPage> pages = db.WikiPages.ToList();

    return View(pages);
}
```